# Is it possible to create a picklist with two targets?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

my requirement is to have a listbox of all users and two listboxes for (send to, send cc)
so that i can drag & drop from list of users the "To" and the "CC"
so i was wondering if it's possible to have a picklist with two targets, and if not, then how to accomplish this requirement ?

thanks.

Comment: Have two separate picklists, one for **TO** and one for **CC**.

Comment: @rags, then i will have the users list duplicated which i don't want

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh It wouldn't be a big deal to duplicate the list.  The user objects themselves are not duplicated because each node of a List is simply a reference to an existing User object.  Multiple nodes in multiple lists can point to the same object so the memory impact is tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of the droppable feature of primefaces Datatable? Have one Datatable with a list of Users on the left hand side of the form and two datatables on the right for "To" and "CC".

```
    http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dndTable.jsf
```

Comment: that's what i finally made it.